# Variable substitution in tcsh

Tags: redhat, tcsh

I've gone through the manual for the tcsh but still can't figure out how it should work in my case or whether it should work at all. I basically need to extract part of the variable whose value is a six digit number. So I need to drop the first two characters and retrieve the last four.

The example below doesn't work (it would probably work in bash but tcsh HAS to be used):

```
set VAR1 = value1
set VAR2 = `echo ${VAR1:2}`
echo VAR2
```

It comes up with error `Bad : modifier in $ (2)`, apparently because it's bash syntax and not understandable by tcsh, but can't figure out how to do it with tcsh arguments.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you find an answer helpful, feel free to accept and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about using modifiers, but you can slice your string using `cut` or `sed`:

```
set VAR1=abcdef
```

"cut" characters 3-to-end

```
echo $VAR1 | cut -c3-
```

capture everything (`\(.*\)`), except for the first 2 characters (`..`)

```
echo $VAR1 | sed 's/..\(.*\)$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the perl command line with regexs like the sed in **@shx2** answer above:

```
echo $VAR1 | perl -pe 's/^\d\d(.*)/$1/'
```

Drops the first two digits it starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly tcsh doesn't accept bash-style modifiers, or vice versa. They're very different shells.

You say you need to extract the last 4 digits of a 6-digit number. I'll assume that number is a non-negative integer.

If you think of it as an arithmetic problem rather than as a string-processing problem, you can use the built-in `@` command:

```
% set VAR1 = 123456
% @ VAR2 = $VAR1 % 10000
% echo VAR1=$VAR1 VAR2=$VAR2
VAR1=123456 VAR2=3456
%
```

(Why do you *have* to use tcsh? Obligatory link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot .)